# Laravel 8 eloquent query delete

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to delete the `aircon` in database when there is no any data.

`Order` and `Aircon` are many to many relationship.

```
$orders = Order::with('aircons', 'user')
                ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
                ->orWhere(//if order->aircons count == 0)->delete()
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `whereDoesntHave`

```php
$orders = Order::with('user')
                ->whereDoesntHave('aircons')
                ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
                ->get();
```

**Edit:**

You can also add new column `aircons_count` will old number of aircons for every order which will be faster than the above query and run the query like the following:

```php
$orders = Order::with('user')
                ->where('aircons_count', '>', 0)
                ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
                ->get();
```

*Note: make sure to add logic every time you add/remove aircon to an order*